# How to upload video on vine programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

In my app , i want to share a video on vine . i search a lot but didn't get proper result for sharing video on vine.

thanks in advance .

Comment: You will need Vine's API

Comment: Thanks for answer , i have vine API in json format download from Github ,but how to use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to https://github.com/VineAPI/VineAPI/blob/master/endpoints.md
You need to Login, Upload thumbnail, Upload video, Create post.

Comment: Thanks for answer , i have vine API in json format download from Github ,but how to use it ?...

Comment: @Garry there is no direct way, you need to make requests by that specification to vine server.

Comment: i m trying to upload video by post method but got an error -code = 101;
    data = "";
    error = "That username or password is incorrect.";
    success = 0;     plz help me out ... thanks

Comment: @ChetanPrajapati - no dude, have u any solution  ?